# Have global adversaries ever been able to decrypt hard drives storing .onion material encrypted by Veracrypt?

Tags: onion-services, encryption

I'm planning on encrypting my entire HDD - which includes Tor .onion service content - using Veracrypt, the latest in encryption technology.

Has Veracrypt been known to successfully encrypt .onion service material stored on HDD? Just how indecipherable would a hard drive encrypted by Veracrypt be and has this level of encryption ever been defeated by a global or state actor?

Comment: Define "successfully".

Comment: I mean, does Veracrypt provide a level of encryption so strong and so indecipherable as to make it virtually immune to forensic analysis or advanced hacking techniques?

Comment: Yes. Without the password, there is no known way to break it. In fact, VeraCrypt uses stronger encryption than even Tor (assuming your password is strong, of course).

Answer (score 1):

these matters are totally unrelated: Tor is a Network layer, sort of speaking, and - HDD security - is a server-layer or service-layer, regardless of the network the Server is exposed to: Internet/Clearnet, Tor, I2P e.t.c..

Comment: I wouldn't say totally unrelated, as both levels of security actually complement and reinforce each other. HDD encryption would further boost the strong anonymity provided by Tor, hence the question about how indecipherable is Veracrypt encryption. I've heard that Veracrypt is a significant improvement over Truecrypt, which did have a number of security flaws.